# cfnetwork memory leaks in iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, cfnetwork

I am getting following type of memory leak in my application - instruments checking. I have properly allocated & deallocated every object. However i am getting this type of memory leak.

std::_Deque_base<__CFURLCacheNode*, std::allocator<__CFURLCacheNode*> >::_M_allocate_node()

What is the reason behind generating these kind of leak?

Why this memory leak is occurred?

Images : -

[alt text http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/9571/problem151.png](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/9571/problem151.png)

[alt text http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/6181/problem152.png](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/6181/problem152.png)

[alt text http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/8035/problem153.png](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/8035/problem153.png)

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/6092/problem154.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/6092/problem154.png)

Comment: Are you calling `[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:]` anywhere in your code ? You should - to set up the shard cache for responses - but you must only do this once in your app (preferably in the app delegate after the app launches). If you call this method more than once in your app, in my experience you will start to see exactly this kind of memory leak.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implement following code in your appDidFinishL. function

there will no leak

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

// Override point for customization after app launch    
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache release];

[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

Comment: This seems to have made the big ones disappear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you profiling on the **phone** or on the **simulator**?

I've heard there are memory leaks in the `NSURLConnection` class when on the simulator.

from http://www.iphonedevforums.com/forum/general-development-questions-advice/1086-memory-leaks.html

> The NSURLConnection class itself has a leak in the sendSynchronousRequest method in OS 2.x. It's an issue that Apple is fully aware of.

Comment: There are still leaks on OS 3.1.2.  I have been going insane trying to understand what was going on.  There are also random crashes within CFNetwork.  I wrote a small sample program that demonstrates the issue so hopefully Apple will fix it.  In the mean time, ASIHTTPRequest is an amazing replacement for NSURLConnection.  Zero leaks, zero crashes so far.